# Debugging in corona sdk

Tags: debugging, coronasdk

I am trying to figure out a debugger in Corona SDK. Currently i am using the most basic technique of print commands but i am looking for a module that could help me put break points and view the value of the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.mydevelopersgames.com/CIDER/ - I'm not sure if you're looking for just a "module", but this IDE has all the features you mentioned. Personally I use it and I'd say it's worth it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I agree with Mr.Unicorn. **CORONA CIDER IDE** provide several features to help coding in lua.
Trial version is also available on their site, you can try it.

Some major features of CIDER:

- Breakpoints
- Omniscient Debugging
- Function Navigator
- Smart Code Completion and many others.

You can check on their site : http://www.mydevelopersgames.com/CIDER/features.html